# Can a holder of a G4 Visa legally receive flight training and/or acquire a Private Pilot Licence?

Tags: faa-regulations, faa, pilot-certification

I am planning to attend a flight school and acquire a PPL, but I am currently staying in the US with a G4 Visa. Am I allowed to receive flight training legally?

Answer (score 1):

You would need an M-1 (for training at a flight school) or F-1 (for training at a college & some flight training academies) Visa to receive flight training.

More information [here](https://www.aopa.org/advocacy/pilots/alien-flight-training-program/visa-information).

Comment: The link you give cites [a regulation](https://www.uscis.gov/ilink/docView/SLB/HTML/SLB/0-0-0-1/0-0-0-11261/0-0-0-17197/0-0-0-17437.html) that prohibits B-1/B-2 visitors from enrolling in school (because those are visitor visas), though recreational studies, if you're just taking lessons for fun, can be a separate thing. [This document](http://bit.ly/2p1cwld) seems to indicate G-4 holders may be able to study. The bit I have no idea about, and why I never answered this question, is whether a G-4 holder can get TSA Alien Flight Student Program approval with a G-4 for flight training.

Comment: While it does not specifically address the GV visa, it does state: "The alien may not enroll in the course of study until the Service has admitted the alien as an F-1 or M-1 nonimmigrant or has approved the alien's application." It also goes on to say the H-type visas can also be used for flight training, however it still says nothing about the G-type visa.